24.04 Network Unclaimed on Lenovo ThinkPad L14
I have an issue with Ubuntu 24.04 I can't connect to the internet. I used the command [sudo lshw -c network] and have the line "Network Unclaimed".
[sudo] password for developer: 
  *-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Network controller
       product: RTL8852AE 802.11ax PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:09:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:3000(size=256) memory:ae200000-ae2fffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: b
       bus info: usb@2:3.1
       logical name: enx9405bb10baf5
       serial: 94:05:bb:10:ba:f5
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8152 driverversion=v1.12.12 duplex=full ip=192.168.1.44 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s


Don't know if I have done this code right:
sudo dpkg -s linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r) | grep Status
dpkg-query: package 'linux-modules-extra-5.14.0-1054-oem' is not installed and no information is available
Use dpkg --info (= dpkg-deb --info) to examine archive files.


$>uname -r
6.8.0-45-generic
$>sudo dpkg -s linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r) | grep Status
[sudo] password for developer:
Status: install ok installed
